# could not load library when executing binary

Tags: android, terminal

I'm trying to run a binary, which is placed on the sdcard, with the terminal *termux*.

```
su -c /sdcard/aapt
```

*(The aapt file actually is from the **termux** app, but I want to run it **manually**)*

The output is

```
    CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "libandroid-cutils.so"needed by "/sdcard/aapt"; caused by library "libandroid-cutils.so" not found
```

I placed the library on the sdcard, too, but it doesn't work.

Where should I place the library that it could be found or what command do I need that the library is loaded?

Comment: Did you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Yes, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set